# Make Coin Flip Animation Two Sided

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I would like this animation taken from animate.css to show a coin with 2 different side and not the same one. I pasted the relevant parts of my code to this Fiddle:
[jsFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/sx0t0kc8/1/)

HTML Code:

```
<div id="coin-flip">
        <button id="btnFlip">Flip the Coin</button></br></br></br>
        <div id="coin-flip-cont">
            <div id="coin"></div>
        </div></br></br></br>
        <h2 id="result"></h2>
 </div>
```

Javascript, jQuery Code:

```
$(function() {
        var coin = {
            sideOne: "./img/image1.png",
            sideTwo: "./img/image2.png"
        }

        $("#btnFlip").click(function() {
            $("#coin").html(`<img class="animated flip"src="${coin[result]}" width="200" length="200"/>`);
        });
});
```

CSS is from Animate.css, You can view it in the Fiddle.

Basically the result I want is the coin to flip showing both different sides and landing on the one that is set by the rest of my code.

EDIT: Just adding this as an example of what I would like to achieve http://codepen.io/html5andblog/pen/ea62c27ddb5c7b022ab1e889e2f1b8d2
I feel that this can be done in a much simpler way and with the css that I already have.

Comment: Your `br` tags are wrong. Change them to `<br />`. If you do `</br>` that implies there was a `<br>` tag somewhere before them.

Comment: @MikeC Thanks, will do. It worked so I never thought there was a difference.

Comment: Simply <br> is sufficient in HTML5. The other form <br /> is there for compatibility with XHTML.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, change this line of your HTML code :

```
<button id="btnFlip">Flip the Coin</button>
```

To :

```
<button id="btnFlip" onclick="coin_flip()">Flip the Coin</button>
```

And then change your javascript to this code :

```
function coin_flip{
var coin_1 = "/images/image_1.png"
var coin_2 = "/images/image_2.png"
// the 8 below is the number of flips in your animation
for (var i = 0 ; i<8 ; i++){
    if (document.getElementById("coin").src == coin_1){
        document.getElementById("coin").src == coin_2
    }
    if (document.getElementById("coin").src == coin_2){
        document.getElementById("coin").src == coin_1
    }
}
// below chooses a random side
var rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1);
document.getElementById("coin").src == "coin_" + rand
}
```

This javascript code flips the coin 8 times before choosing a random side to land on.

Comment: And to make this change images while the animation is running?

Comment: it should be `"coin_" + rand` on the last row

Answer (score 0):

you can use **animationend** event to detect when the CSS animation ended.

Then you execute code to change the image source.

**JQuery**

```
$('#coin').on('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend',   
function(e) {

    $("#coin").removeClass('animateCoin');
    setTimeout(function() {
            var srcImg = $($('#coin img')[0]).attr('src');
            if (srcImg === coin.heads)
                $($('#coin img')[0]).attr('src',coin.tails);
            else
                $($('#coin img')[0]).attr('src',coin.heads);
            $("#coin").addClass('animateCoin');
    },50);          
});
```

**CSS :**

```
.animateCoin {
    animation: flip 1s;
}
```

Comment: Won't this execute the animation with one image and then change it to another?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete code you can flip coin 2 sided solution run snippet.
To watch correct result see in full page view otherwise you can see on codepen.
You can have link of codepen too [click here](https://codepen.io/abobaker/pen/wQRpyb)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

 var spinArray = ['animation900','animation1080','animation1260','animation1440','animation1620','animation1800','animation1980','animation2160'];

 function getSpin() {
 var spin = spinArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*spinArray.length)];
 return spin;
 }

 $('#flip').on('click', function(){

 $('#coin').removeClass();

 setTimeout(function(){
 $('#coin').addClass(getSpin());
 }, 100);

 });

 });
```

```css
html, body {
 margin: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #333;
 }

 #coin-flip-cont {
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 position: absolute;
 top: calc(50% - 100px);
 left: calc(50% - 100px);
 }

 #coin {
 position: relative;
 width: 200px;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 }

 #coin .front, #coin .back {
 position: absolute;
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 }

 #coin .front {
 transform: translateZ(1px);
 border-radius: 50%;
 background-color: #3498db;
  border: solid 5px gray;
 }

 #coin .back {
 transform: translateZ(-1px) rotateY(180deg);
 border-radius: 50%;
 background-color: #2ecc71;
  border: solid 5px gray;
 }

 #coin.animation900 {
 -webkit-animation: rotate900 3s linear forwards; 
 animation: rotate900 3s linear forwards;
 }

 #coin.animation1080 {
 -webkit-animation: rotate1080 3s linear forwards; 
 animation: rotate1080 3s linear forwards;
 }

 #coin.animation1260 {
 -webkit-animation: rotate1260 3s linear forwards; 
 animation: rotate1260 3s linear forwards;
 }

 #coin.animation1440 {
 -webkit-animation: rotate1440 3s linear forwards; 
 animation: rotate1440 3s linear forwards;
 }

 #coin.animation1620 {
 -webkit-animation: rotate1620 3s linear forwards; 
 animation: rotate1620 3s linear forwards;
 }

 #coin.animation1800 {
 -webkit-animation: rotate1800 3s linear forwards; 
 animation: rotate1800 3s linear forwards;
 }

 #coin.animation1980 {
 -webkit-animation: rotate1980 3s linear forwards; 
 animation: rotate1980 3s linear forwards;
 }

 #coin.animation2160 {
 -webkit-animation: rotate2160 3s linear forwards; 
 animation: rotate2160 3s linear forwards;
 }

 @-webkit-keyframes rotate900 {
 from { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0); -moz-transform: rotateY(0); transform: rotateY(0); }
 to { -webkit-transform: rotateY(900deg); -moz-transform: rotateY(900deg); transform: rotateY(900deg); }
 }

 @keyframes rotate900 {
 from { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0); -moz-transform: rotateY(0); transform: rotateY(0); }
 to { -webkit-transform: rotateY(900deg); -moz-transform: rotateY(900deg); transform: rotateY(900deg); }
 }

 @-webkit-keyframes rotate1080 {
 from { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0); -moz-transform: rotateY(0); transform: rotateY(0); }
 to { -webkit-transform: rotateY(1080deg); -moz-transform: rotateY(1080deg); transform: rotateY(1080deg); }
 }

 @keyframes rotate1080 {
 from { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0); -moz-transform: rotateY(0); transform: rotateY(0); }
 to { -webkit-transform: rotateY(1080deg); -moz-transform: rotateY(1080deg); transform: rotateY(1080deg); }
 }

 @-webkit-keyframes rotate1260 {
 from { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0); -moz-transform: rotateY(0); transform: rotateY(0); }
 to { -webkit-transform: rotateY(1260deg); -moz-transform: rotateY(1260deg); transform: rotateY(1260deg); }
 }

 @keyframes rotate1260 {
 from { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0); -moz-transform: rotateY(0); transform: rotateY(0); }
 to { -webkit-transform: rotateY(1260deg); -moz-transform: rotateY(1260deg); transform: rotateY(1260deg); }
 }

 @-webkit-keyframes rotate1440 {
 from { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0); -moz-transform: rotateY(0); transform: rotateY(0); }
 to { -webkit-transform: rotateY(1440deg); -moz-transform: rotateY(1440deg); transform: rotateY(1440deg); }
 }

 @keyframes rotate1440 {
 from { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0); -moz-transform: rotateY(0); transform: rotateY(0); }
 to { -webkit-transform: rotateY(1440deg); -moz-transform: rotateY(1440deg); transform: rotateY(1440deg); }
 }

 @-webkit-keyframes rotate1620 {
 from { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0); -moz-transform: rotateY(0); transform: rotateY(0); }
 to { -webkit-transform: rotateY(1620deg); -moz-transform: rotateY(1620deg); transform: rotateY(1620deg); }
 }

 @keyframes rotate1620 {
 from { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0); -moz-transform: rotateY(0); transform: rotateY(0); }
 to { -webkit-transform: rotateY(1620deg); -moz-transform: rotateY(1620deg); transform: rotateY(1620deg); }
 }

 @-webkit-keyframes rotate1800 {
 from { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0); -moz-transform: rotateY(0); transform: rotateY(0); }
 to { -webkit-transform: rotateY(1800deg); -moz-transform: rotateY(1800deg); transform: rotateY(1800deg); }
 }

 @keyframes rotate1800 {
 from { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0); -moz-transform: rotateY(0); transform: rotateY(0); }
 to { -webkit-transform: rotateY(1800deg); -moz-transform: rotateY(1800deg); transform: rotateY(1800deg); }
 }

 @-webkit-keyframes rotate1980 {
 from { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0); -moz-transform: rotateY(0); transform: rotateY(0); }
 to { -webkit-transform: rotateY(1980deg); -moz-transform: rotateY(1980deg); transform: rotateY(1980deg); }
 }

 @keyframes rotate1980 {
 from { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0); -moz-transform: rotateY(0); transform: rotateY(0); }
 to { -webkit-transform: rotateY(1980deg); -moz-transform: rotateY(1980deg); transform: rotateY(1980deg); }
 }

 @-webkit-keyframes rotate2160 {
 from { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0); -moz-transform: rotateY(0); transform: rotateY(0); }
 to { -webkit-transform: rotateY(2160deg); -moz-transform: rotateY(2160deg); transform: rotateY(2160deg); }
 }

 @keyframes rotate2160 {
 from { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0); -moz-transform: rotateY(0); transform: rotateY(0); }
 to { -webkit-transform: rotateY(2160deg); -moz-transform: rotateY(2160deg); transform: rotateY(2160deg); }
 }
.button {
  background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-top: 125px;
  position: inherit;
}
.front-text{
    font-weight: 700 !important;
    margin-top: 45%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center>
   <div>
     <div id="coin-flip-cont">
       <div id="coin">
            <div class="front"><p class="front-text">Head</p></div>
            <div class="back"><p class="front-text">Tail</p></div>
       </div>
     </div>
     <button type="button" id="flip" class="button"> Flip Coin</button>
   </div>
</center>
```